# Applying nlminb to subsets of data (by index or label) and store what the program returns as a new data frame

Tags: data-structures, r, subset

I was wondering if anyone could kindly help me with this seemingly easy task.  I'm using nlminb to conduct optimization and compute some statistics by index. Here's an example from nlminb help.

```
> x <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10)
> hdev <- function(par) {
+     -sum(dnbinom(x, mu = par[1], size = par[2], log = TRUE))
+ }
> nlminb(c(9, 12), hdev)
$par
[1] 9.730000 5.954936
$objective
[1] 297.2074
$convergence
[1] 0
$message
[1] "relative convergence (4)"
$iterations
[1] 10
$evaluations
function gradient
      12       27
```

Suppose I generate random variables `x, y`, and `z` where `z` acts as an index (from 1 to 3).

```
> x <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10)
> y <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10)
> z <- rep(1:3, length=100)
> A <- cbind(x,y,z)
> hdev <- function(par) {
+     -sum(dnbinom(x+y, mu = par[1], size = par[2], log = TRUE))}
```

1. How can I apply `nlminb(c(9, 12), hdev)` to the data set by index `z`? In other words, I would like to compute `nlminb(c(9, 12), hdev)` for `z=1, z=2`, and `z=3` separately. I tried `by(A, z, function(A) nlminb(c(9,12), hdev))` and `sparseby(A, z, function(A) nlminb(c(9,12), hdev))`, but they return exactly the same values for each value of `z`.
2. I would like to turn each output into a new data frame so that it will become a 3X2 matrix.

   [1] Z1_ANSWER_1 Z1_ANSWER_2
   [2] Z2_ANSWER_1 Z2_ANSWER_2
   [3] Z3_ANSWER_1 Z3_ANSWER_2

Since nlminb returns the summary of statistics, I needed to use `CASEZ1<-nlminb$par, CASEZ2<-nlminb$par, CASEZ3<-nlminb$par` and then use `cbind` to combine them. However, I would like to automate this process as the real data I'm working on has a lot more categories than `z` presented here.

If I'm not making myself clear, please let me know. I'll see if I can replicate the actual data set and functions I'm working on (I just don't have them on this computer).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try an approach

```
x <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10)
y <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10)
z <- rep(1:3, length=100)
A <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

At first load the `plyr` library

```
library(plyr)
```

The following code returns the results for each z

```
dlply(A, .(z), function(x) {
    hdev <- function(par, mydata) {-sum(dnbinom(mydata, mu = par[1], size = par[2], log = TRUE))}
    nlminb(c(9, 12), hdev, mydata=t(as.vector(x[1] + as.vector(x[2]))))
}
)
```

Now, with this one you will get a 3x2 dataframe with the $par results

```
ddply(A, .(z), function(x) {
    hdev <- function(par, mydata) {-sum(dnbinom(mydata, mu = par[1], size = par[2], log = TRUE))}
    res <- nlminb(c(9, 12), hdev, mydata=t(as.vector(x[1] + as.vector(x[2]))))
    return(res$par)
}
)
```

Comment: Magically, it works! Let me take a close look at plyr. Thanks a lot!